# SQL for data logging?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, logging

I'm getting started on a project to build an advanced scientific instrument. Over the course of developing the instrument, we will do alot of testing and therefor be logging alot of data. The data will consist of alot of datapoints and corresponding measurement values at different points in time. At any given point in time, there will likely be an incomplete set of datapoint measurements.
Lets say the data would be roughly 100-200 floating points sampled once per second each over 4 months of operation. So the data rate would be a few kB (5 at most) per second to disk.

I'm looking for an effective method to store all of this data and be able to access it and plot trends in various data points over time, preferably from anywhere on the network. I would also like to have a softare API so that our automated test software can access the database to log data.

I came across SQLite and I think this might be a good tool. Based on reading some basic tutorials, most of them use simpler examples where there may not be a need for history/trending aspect. So I was wondering from some more experienced with SQL whether it would be an appropriate tool for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: First, I would define some specific details about what is to be stored. How it is obtained and volume and rates of generation of data, Some examples of what will needed to be displayed etc. Only then would I start to look at physical resources required? Currently, you have nothing concrete to discuss and come to any meaningful conclusions? Interesting - maybe. suitable for SO - not so much at this point.

Comment: One concern is  data rates your testing tools generate when logging. I'd better log source data to plain files at real time and then loaded it into DB offline.

Comment: Edited with some specifics

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But we would want to be able to look at old data and study relationships between different data points over time.

Comment: Backing up is a good question. This is a big budget project, so I should be able to justify any expense that makes sense. We also have some institutional resources (ex: servers) that we can probably use for backup.

Comment: It looks like your total data will be less than 200 GB? Not sure that would be considered a lot of data - even for a pc? But you question talks about a lot of data?

Comment: Correct. It's just some status data for one or two instruments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite works great as high performance local engine for data collection.
However, SQLite was NOT designed to be able to serve your data over the network - you need server-based SQL engine for that, for example MySQL or PostgreSQL.

I would recommend to log your data into local SQLite database, and then import this data in background operation to MySQL or PostgreSQL server (perhaps every day or every hour).
This method will allow you to have data logged locally even if network connectivity is interrupted or PostgreSQL server is down for maintenance. At the same time, if done properly (using transactions for batching burst loads), SQLite can offer excellent performance for very high incoming data speeds.

Also, it is quite common that raw measurements contain a lot of data that need to be summarized before going into longer storage. SQLite will be perfect for that - you can group, average or otherwise summarize your data using standard SQL before you put it into PostgreSQL.

If you are absolutely sure that network connectivity is not an issue, you can forego SQLite as intermediate storage and log directly into PostgreSQL - this will make your solution a lot simpler, at the price of losing some reliability.

Comment: Does it matter that the number of users reading the data will be very small? (not more than 5 or 10)

Comment: @kjgregory: no, SQLite is local by definition. Granted, you can create PHP page reading that data from single local SQLite table and serve it on webpage, but that web server must run on host that does the measurement.

Comment: Follow-up question: I'm looking at using the pysql API (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-functions-and-constants). What changes if/when I want to convert my application to use PostgreSQL?

Comment: @kjgregory: for postgresql, use library psycopg2. Its interface is virtually identical to python sqlite library.